# Pdf.js Express/PdfTron - Double Click Event Listener

Tags: pdf, events, listener, pdf.js, pdf.js.express

i am using PDF.JS from https://pdfjs.express/ and currently i am stuck at registering events on the pdf.

What am i looking for?

As soon as the user double clicks a word in the pdf document, i want to retrieve e.g. the clicked word or maybe even all words nearby.

Why? So i can exactly locate where the user clicked and show the position in the equivalent text editor.

Any suggestions?

I researched all docs related to pdf.js but didnt find any hint.

Thanks!